# Is it possible to change color depth in KDE in user mode?

Tags: linux, colors, kde

I want to increase the color depth for my user account in kde. I cannot edit the configuration in /etc/X11. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to change this outside of the xorg.conf configuration.  You can look here:

http://www.x.org/archive/current/doc/man/man5/xorg.conf.5.xhtml

If the variables are available for run-time configuration they will say:

> "and the value can be changed at run−time with xset(1) ..."

You can see the Depth settings don't have run-time configurations:

> DefaultDepth depth
>
> specifies which color depth the server should use by default. The
>   −depth command line option can be used to override this. If neither is
>   specified, the default depth is driver−specific, but in most cases is
>   8.
>
> DefaultFbBpp bpp
>
> specifies which framebuffer layout to use by default. The −fbbpp
>   command line option can be used to override this. In most cases the
>   driver will chose the best default value for this. The only case where
>   there is even a choice in this value is for depth 24, where some
>   hardware supports both a packed 24 bit framebuffer layout and a sparse
>   32 bit framebuffer layout.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked into this and although what I found didn't solve my problem, it answered my question.  The simple solution is to build a xorg.conf file

```
Xorg :1 -configure
```

this produces an xorg.conf.new file.  You can then modify it adding

```
Section "Screen"
    ...
    DefaultDepth 24
    ...
EndSection
```

Then you place that file in `/etc/X11/` or similar

This worked in so far as it made the color depth 24 but it seems my issue was an incorrect driver or something of that sort.

Comment: But that's not user mode.  Glad you figured it out though.